# Using function.prototype.bind directly on function declaration

Tags: javascript

Why is this allowed ?

```
var f = function() {
  console.log(this.x);
}.bind({x:1})();
```

And why this is not or better why I get syntax error in this case ?

```
function f() {
  console.log(this.x);
}.bind({x:1})();
```

So, why I need **function expression** syntax to get this work and is there a way to use `bind` method directly on **function declaration** ?

Comment: A function declaration is not an expression, so you can't do that. But you can force an expression `!function f(){}.bind({x:1})()`. Look for info on [IIFE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript).

Comment: Do you know why is not allowed on declaration ?

Comment: Because it is not an expression. The syntax is ambiguous, you have to disambiguate by forcing an expression. Check the spec for more info http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13

Comment: Thanks, this is one more reason for throwing away function declaration and always using expression form. I can use methods directly, no hoisting...

Answer (score 4):

The second example works but the syntax is slightly off:

Surround the function in parens. I have to say that I'm not entirely sure why. It seems like it would work without the parens huh? :P

```
(function f() {
    console.log(this.x);
}).bind({x:1})();
```

Comment: parens make an expression, and thus an anon function, and thus a "tail value". you can also do the prefix-only alternative to paren wraps: `0||`